# Serialize a column based on sorting order?

Tags: mariadb

I have a column `number_order` and `products_name` I'm struggling to build a command that will sort by A-Z so that respectively:

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
```

I'm using MariaDB. To be clear I want to run a command that will set the `number_order` starting from 1 to X, based on the `products_name` so that a product called A would have `number_order` = 1

Comment: *a command that will sort by A-Z* The sorting is performed by using ORDER BY clause in the query with proper sorting expression. In your case `ORDER BY product_name` is enough.

Comment: @Akina see my edit, this is not what I'm struggling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE sourcetable
SET number_order = (@tmp := @tmp + 1)
WHERE NOT (@tmp := 0) 
ORDER BY products_name ASC
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5634d1c8d1d8c36cf4e642e63bfc5c3d)

Comment: "Assignments within ... are deprecated  and will be removed in future versions " in MySQL 8.  Any suggested alternative solutions to `:=`  in the `SET` statement?

Comment: @agone In MySQL 8 you must use ROW_NUMBER()